# How to use "?" within WINDOWS 10 SEARCH

Tags: windows-10, search

Question:
Under WINDOWS 10 SEARCH

Doing a search for  "???.txt"
Is it EXCLUSIVELY  3 character long ?    Not more , not less
Or will it also include  1 and 2  character long file ?

thanks
clem

Answer (score 0):

Windows Search has two wildcards `*` and `?`.

**Question Mark** `?`

This will search for unknown characters of exactly the same number of `?` in the search string.

For example: `img_???.jpg` will return results such as `img_123.jpg`, `img_124.jpg`, and `img_125.jpg`. It will not return results like `img_1234.jpg`, or `img_12.jpg`.

**Asterisk** `*`

This will search for unknown strings. It will return results with any length.

For example: `*.jpg` will return results such as `img_123.jpg`, `img_124.jpg`, and `cat.jpg`. Anything that matches `<something>.jpg` will be found.